# Can't run more than one LibGDX game

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, libgdx, game-development

I have developed a game with LibGDX library.
I am using socket programming libraries as a module in the project.

I am planing that every process of my LibGDX game will be a client for my server.
I structured it.

But I can't run more than one game at a time to test multiplayer functionality.
When I run the game first, everything is okay, but the second time I click run anything run until the first instance is closed.

I think that's because of Gradle.

I tried to change "Build and run using IntelliJ Idea" from Gradle settings, but this time I had an exception. It cannot read my assets file.

How can I solve this problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcmb8.png)

Comment: What Run/Debug Configuration do you use?

Comment: You can see my configurations from the image above.

Comment: Does it work if you launch Run Configuration from the toolbar Run(Debug) icon and not from Run Anything popup?

Comment: No, the Second task will be waiting in the queue for the first project to be finished. That's because of Gradle. When I stop the first process, the second is going to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it with a Gradle command.

`./gradlew desktop:run`

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here. Desktop app starts but gradle build never ends and all following builds have to wait until I exit the app or stop the gradle build process.

Setting the "allow multiple instances" option in the Application run configuration did not help.

Making a gradle configuration with "desktop:run" has the same effect and "allow parallel run" did not help.

This started after the Android Studio updating to version "Arctic Fox 2020.3.1"

Starting from command line with "./gradlew desktop:run" in several terminal windows works, but is laborious.

---

**Update with a temporary solution (until the error is fixed):**
[image]

Create a JAR-Application run configuration. Build the jar in the "before launch" section with Gradle task "desktop:dist" and point to the jar in "Path to JAR".

**Hints:**

- You can safely ignore all the "xmas" strings in the image :)
- "XstartOnFirstThread" is only necessary on Mac OS.
- On some recent "intellij/android studio" versions is a bug that breaks "desktop:dist" the solution is to include "duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE" in desktop/build.gradle:

  ```
   task dist(type: Jar) {
   manifest {
       attributes 'Main-Class': project.mainClassName
   }
   dependsOn configurations.runtimeClasspath

   duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE

   from {
       configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
   }
   with jar
  ```

  }

Answer (score 0):

Enable **Allow multiple instances** option in Run/Debug Configuration:

[image]

Comment: In Run/Debug Configuration, I have already checked "Allow Parallel Run". But I cannot see "Allow multiple instances".